# cannot display pdf (jain product - 21 (1).pdf is of invalid format) in mobile

Tags: php, android, html, mobile

```
<?php namespace Dompdf;
require_once '../dopdf/autoload.inc.php';
include('../mainconn.php');
$link=basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."?";
$cnt =0;
$fnim=$_GET['name']." - ".$_GET['oid'];
$sqlem13 = $conn->prepare("select * from  orders where cid =:yes and status =3");
$sqlem13 -> bindParam(':yes',$_GET['i']);
$sqlem13 ->execute();
$hdata="<html><head><title>Order of </title>
</head><body>MYDATA</body></html>";
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml($hdata);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("jain product - 21 (1)",array("Attachment" => TRUE)); ?>
```

it will open in android bcos it open in computer well

[image]